# How are enumerations different from classes?

Tags: java, enums

I am new to Java and to me enumerations and classes look a lot similar to me except the fact that enumerations have pre built constants. So, I wanted to ask two things. How are enumerations and classes different and why should we use enumerations instead of class?

Comment: You would use an enumeration when you can enumerate all the possible instances.  You would use a class when you can't say in advance how many instances you would have (or subclasses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerations *are* classes.  They extend the `Enum` [parent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

I think of enumerations as typesafe, restricted, self-describing lists of constants that my application will use.  You don't use them instead of classes; they're complimentary.

You choose to use an enumeration if you have a finite list of related constants.